# QGIS Merged Layers/ Cannot Find Windows "minidump" to Restore Past version off Dropbox

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.2, dropbox

I've copied a layer style and was playing around with the display of a point layer when QGIS Valmiera 2.2 crashed. A recently-created polygon layers attributes are now appearing in the place of another polygon layer with 100x more features, although the displayed feature count is still 506 instead of the 4 in the table. As the program crashed, it flashed a message as to where the minidump was located- not sure how to find it.

I attempted to restore previous versions of the layer and all associated files from Dropbox, but received an error of "permission denied". I verified that I have full access to AppData\Temp, which makes me believe that Temp is not the folder I should be searching in. Please help me find this folder or reload the 506 features and hours of work!

Answer (score 1):

The minidump file should be located (atleast it is for me using Windows 7) at:

```
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Note that you may have to **unhide** all the folders, subfolders and files. I received one today infact due to a plugin not responding. The file will have a name similar to:

```
qgis-20150227-111146-6356-5280-e2a51df.dmp
```

The `20150227` set of numbers is the date of which it is created.

If you used a processing function, your layers may be saved in a folder in the following temporary directory:

```
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\
```

Your file may be in a folder, probably the easiest way to check is when the date of the folder/file was modified.

Hope this helps!